# Deleted neighborhoods in first countable space

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let X - first countable. Is it true, that for every deleted neighborhood $Oa$ and for every finite subset in X, there is another deleted neighborhood $Ua$ such that $Ua\subset Oa\setminus M$?.

So, taking $Oa$ as $Oa\setminus \{a\}$, is it true, that $\forall a\in X,\ \forall Oa$ $\forall M \subset X (M<∞ \rightarrow \exists Ua\subset Oa\setminus M)$?

Comment: No, take $(X,\tau)$ with $X=\{a,b\}$, $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{b\}, \{a,b\}\}$, $O_a=\{b\}$ and $M=\{b\}$. $\emptyset$ is not a deleted neighbourhood of $a$ because $\{a\}$ isn't open.

Comment: What does "taking $Oa$ as $Oa \setminus \{a\}$" mean? Either $Oa$ contains $a$ or it does not.

Comment: @Paul Frost means $Oa$ - deleted neighborhood

Comment: If $Oa$ is a deleted neighborhood, what is $Oa \setminus \{a\}$? Do yo mean $Oa  =O\setminus \{a\}$ if $O$ is a neighborhood of $a$?

Comment: However, it is true if $X$ is Hausdorff, or even $T_1$, whether $X$ is first countable or not. For each $m \in M$, select a neighborhood of $U_m$ of $a$ that misses $M$. Since $M$ is finite, the set $Ua = Oa \cap \bigcap_{m\in M} U_m$ is such a deleted neighborhood.

Comment: Right, thanks. I also found that i need T1 for this.